# How do I internationalize my Django website into other languages like Spanish from English?

Tags: django

How do I internationalize my Django website into other languages like Spanish from English?

Answer (score 7):

The [i18n](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#topics-i18n) docs show how.